# Scipy cdist() pass arguments to metric

Tags: scipy

Is there a way to pass additional arguments to my custom metric using cdist()? I tried just adding an extra keyword but I get an error:

```
def distanceMetric(x, y, radius=1):
    return x - y + radius

def test(xs, ys, radius=1):
    return cdist(xs, ys, metric=distanceMetric, radius=radius)
```

And when I run:

```
test([[1],[2],[3]], [[5],[6],[7]])
```

I get an error message saying:

```
TypeError: cdist() got an unexpected keyword argument 'radius'
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue.  Without it, we have to guess too much about your code.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  That code works for me using SciPy 1.0.0.  Which version of SciPy are you using?  You can find the version with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: I am using 0.19.1. It seems that there is no kwargs option in this version: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist

Comment: Yes, that feature was added in 1.0.0: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handling of keyword arguments in `cdist` was added in SciPy 1.0.0.  If you can't upgrade, you can modify the call of `cdist` in your `test` function to something like this:

```
def test(xs, ys, radius=1):
    return cdist(xs, ys, metric=lambda x, y, radius=radius: distanceMetric(x, y, radius))
```